# Difference between db2 export and jdbc

Tags: jdbc, db2

To download millions of records from DB2 shall I use DB2 export or JDBC? Not sure which one is faster and better in terms of resource consumption.

Suggestions please.

Comment: "Better" according to what criteria?

Comment: Better in terms of speed. Which one can download the records at a faster rate?

Comment: JDBC cannot download anything, it is just an API specification. I'm almost sure you can run the DB2 `export` command faster than you can write and debug a Java application, using JDBC, to do the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

If you are interested in downloading the results from a query on a table, you can use the export command:

```
export to file.del of del 
messages export.msg 
select * from table;
```

If you want to download an entire database for backup or migration, there are utilities such as backup and db2move that could be faster.

In either case, you would need to establish a connection to the database, and one connectivity option is JDBC.